# Человек-глагол и человек-прилагательное

Tags: морфология

У меня вот какой вопрос возник, после просмотра роликов одного бизнес-тренера, руководителя некоторой "академии" с заявкой на научные методы и верификацию.

С его точки зрения, можно всех людей определённым образом разделить на три условные группы по способу мышления (в зависимости от того, какие отделы головного мозга привыкли "работать"), при этом в описаниях [видимо, для наглядности] начали проскальзывать ярлыки "человек-глагол" (чаще в речи использует глаголы, для него они более привычный способ описания), "человек-прилагательное" и "человек-существительное". Есть даже забавное упражнение "если бы сказку про колобка написать используя одни глаголы или одни существительные".

Так вот, мне стало любопытно: есть ли какая-то фактологическая и научная база, которая подтверждает подобные построения или опровергает? Я знаю, что филологи делают частотный анализ произведений ну условно Пушкина, можно делать выводы о авторстве в спорных случаях (сразу вспоминается "Тихий Дон") и т.п.

Может ли кто рассказать или хотя бы привести ссылки на исследования, в которых бы анализировалась речь "среднего" человека, чтобы можно было как-то представить себе насколько часто употребляются те или иные части речи, в каких диапазонах обычно варьируются части речи и есть ли какие-то закономерности связанные с этим.

Answer (score 4):

Мнения подобных "тренеров" не имеют ничего общего ни с наукой, ни со здравым смыслом. Подобная классификация антинаучна, и это легко доказать на пальцах.

Большинство численно измеримых показателей, на которые влияет великое множество факторов и которые проявляются в разных мерах в многократно повторяющихся ситуациях, имеют [нормальное распределение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), которое выражается подобными графиками:

[image]

Рост человека, вес, длина пальцев, частота зевания, агрессивность, интеллект — всё описывается нормальным распределением. Нет оснований считать, что частота использования частей речи не подвержена тому же нормальному распределению.

Что же следует из нормального распределения? В первую очередь для нас важно, что большинство людей находится близко к середине. Если мы проводим водораздел между людьми-глаголами и людьми-неглаголами аккуратно посередине, то это означает, что очень большой процент людей окажется очень близко к середине, и принадлежность классу, который должен каким-то образом описывать *ключевые характеристики* человека, окажется подвержена банальным *погрешностям* измерения. При этом людей, которые находятся далеко от середины, и которых корректно приписывать к классам, будет относительно немного.

Это проблема, с которой сталкивается [соционика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) — псевдонаучная теория о классификации людей в соответствии с некоторыми личными качествами. Характеристики, на которых соционика строит классы, описываются нормальным распределением, поэтому классификация хрупкая и непрактичная.

Абсолютно аналогично бессмысленно и деление на людей, которые чаще употребляют в речи какие-либо части речи. Мало того, что измерение будет очень сложным (мы все меняем стиль речи постоянно в зависимости от ситуации), так и классификация будет хрупкой: если я встал не с той ноги, то я окажусь **человеком-междометием**.

Подобные теории очень легко подхватываются массовыми медиа, потому что их легко "продать" читателям: не нужно никаких знаний, вот красивая классификация, а вот тут ещё можно тестик пройти. А дальше уже вступает в силу [эффект Барнума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0), и доверчивые читатели потребляют взахлёб "научную версию" старых-добрых гороскопов.

Comment: Остается задуматься о нормальности распределения роста пигмеев. Да, в популяции пигмеев их рост будет распределен  нормально.     Ну, и т.д. и т.п. .... В конечном итоге, понятно, что говорить о нормальности распределения величины какого-либо признака имеет смысл применительно к группе схожих по определенным характеристикам объектов. Т.о. антинаучность теории на пальцах не доказывается.

Comment: @avp Названия классов предполагают первичность лингвистических характеристик.